# How to import existing app to APEX via SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, sqlplus

I have an existing test app. My config is Windows 10, APEX 19.1, Database Express 18.4

I try to import app by sqlplus:

```
> sqlplus 
> User name: sys as sysdba
> Password: 1234
SQL>@install_KB.sql
```

And i`l get many errors that's starts with:

```
apex_application_install.set_workspace_id (100101);
  *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL.SET_WORKSPACE_ID' must be
declared

ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL.SET_APPLICATION_ID' must be
declared
...
```

My source from *install_KB.sql*:

```
spool install-apex-KB.log
@@APEX/kb_apex_0.0.1.sql
@@DB/security_2.1.0.sql
spool off
```

and source of kb_*apex_0.0.1.sql*:

```
declare
   workspace_id number    := 100101; 
   app_id number          := 62305999; 
   app_owner varchar2(32) := 'test'; 
   app_alias varchar2(32) := 'testapp';

begin 
  apex_application_install.set_workspace_id (workspace_id);
  apex_application_install.set_application_id(app_id);
  apex_application_install.set_schema(app_owner);
  apex_application_install.set_application_alias(app_alias);
end;
/

@@kb_0.0.1.sql
```

What i`m doing wrong? Sorry if answer is obvious

UPD: 
My Schema Assignments list - [image: My Schema Assignments list]
Application Developers and Users - [image: Application Developers and Users]

Comment: You should not be importing the application as "sys", it would be the Oracle schema that the workspace is associated with. You shouldn't need to do all of those apex_application_install calls, you should simply be able to run the SQL that contains the exported application.

Comment: @AdamvonNieda tnx, for response. My APEX login password is ADMIN:1234 and i tried: _"sqlplus ADMIN/1234"_ than _"sqlplus ADMIN/1234@localhost:8080"_ than _"sqlplus ADMIN/1234@localhost:1521/XE"_ and than _"sqlplus ADMIN/1234@localhost:8080/XE"_ . Strange, but i got only `ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

Comment: Yeah, that's not an Oracle database user, it's an APEX user, they're different. You need to find out the workspace to schema assignment where the application is installed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Got it, right connect access is: **sqlplus text/1234@localhost:1521/XEPDB1**

Answer (score 1):

I don't use any of those "apex_application_install" calls when I migrate apps from one environment to the next. I simply connect to the database via SQL*Plus as the user / schema associated with the workspace, and run the exported application .sql file (which was exported via [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html))

I know there are times when you might want to change an application ID etc., but if everything in the target environment is the same, keep it simple.

Import script examples: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/Import-Script-Examples.html#GUID-3FA670B9-823F-4630-9E0E-29F3A61666F2)

To get Workspace to schema assignment in SQL*Plus, you can use the following example, where APEX_180200 is the APEX schema, and 'ADAM'
is the workspace. Or log in to the admin side of APEX and go to "Manage Workspaces" / "Manage Workspace to Schema Assignments" Note that in the example below, my workspace and schema are both named "ADAM".

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
...
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = APEX_180200;
SQL> SELECT APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.GET_SCHEMAS('ADAM') FROM DUAL;
APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.GET_SCHEMAS('ADAM')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADAM  

SQL>
```

Admin GUI

[image: Administration GUI]

Comment: My Workspace: _test_, Schema: _test_.  I tried set schema: `SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = APEX_180200;` and so `APEX_190100` but got 
ERROR: ORA-01435: user does not exist :(

Comment: OK, so if you know that the schema is test, connect to the database as test, and run you application import script.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answers and patience... I tried `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = TEST;` but got same error `ERROR: ORA-01435: user does not exist`

Comment: What I'm saying is since you know that the schema / workspace are both "TEST", connect to the database as "TEST", and run the application script. That's all. @install_KB.sql - If the TEST schema doesn't exist in the target database, then you need to do the steps to install APEX, create the TEST schema etc.